# How to generate empty migration in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF Core migrations to upgrade my database schema and my data.

As I write new C# code, I need to change the data in my different database environments: development, test, industrialisation, staging and production.

Because I don't want to execute a SQL script in as many environments I have, my goal is to put some data migration in a C# migration. Then the data migration will be executed with the other schemas migrations. Preventing me from forgetting.

How can I create an empty C# migration script to change my data with calling SQL, even if I have no database change?

Comment: Thanks to Akash showing an answer that works both in CLI and Powershell, and to JowJoris for an answer showing the generated code whe I can insert the SQL calling migrationBuilder.Sql("Update ...");. I had to throw a coin to decide who deserved the accepted anwer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any changes in data models, when you run the below command, there will be an empty migration file. Then you can put the data manipulation sql code in `Up` method and revert sql code in `Down` method :

**cli :**

```
dotnet ef migrations add [migrationName]
```

**package manager console :**

```
Add-Migration [migrationName]
```

Comment: If you have changes though I haven't found any flag to force empty creation

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty migration with the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Add-Migration '[Insert name]'
```

Your new migration file will look like this:

```
public partial class [Insert name]: Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        
    }
}
```